# Creating PGP key for file encryption in a single command

Tags: gnupg

I am looking for a single, non-interactive command to generate a PGP key that can be used for file encryption.

According to the `gpg` docs, I should be able to run this to create a key capable of encryption:

```
gpg --batch --passphrase '' --yes --default-new-key-algo ed25519 --quick-gen-key "<hello@example.com>" default default
```

However, when I go to encrypt a file with it, it says there is no suitable public key:

```
$ gpg --batch --encrypt --recipient "hello@example.com" --trust-model always --output README.md.gpg README.md
gpg: error retrieving 'hello@example.com' via Local: Unusable public key
gpg: error retrieving 'hello@example.com' via WKD: No data
gpg: hello@example.com: skipped: No data
gpg: README.md: encryption failed: No data
```

I have a feeling that it is because the encryption sub-key is not being created, but I am not sure how to get the command to work according to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can't encrypt data with `ed25519` algorithm (it's not a cipher), it's only a **digital signature scheme** to sign or authenticate you (with `SSH` for example).

> In public-key cryptography, Edwards-curve Digital Signature Algorithm
> (EdDSA) is a digital signature scheme using a variant of Schnorr
> signature based on twisted Edwards curves. It is designed to be
> faster than existing digital signature schemes without sacrificing
> security.

[Reference here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA)

**However**, you can use it for the main key to **sign** other subkeys or data (for example your emails). For encryption cipher, I would recommend you `RSA` with 4096 bits to be really safe. The command to generate the master key + the subkey in your case is as follow :

```
gpg --batch --full-gen-key <<EOF
Key-Type: EDDSA
Key-Curve: ed25519
Key-Usage: sign
Subkey-Type: RSA
Subkey-Length: 4096
Subkey-Usage: encrypt
Name-Real: Hello Example
Name-Email: hello@example.com
Expire-Date: 0
Passphrase: ""
EOF
```

Then you can encrypt your file with :

```
gpg --out file.gpg --encrypt --recipient hello@example.com file
```

By the way, usually, you need to encrypt the file with another's public key person and sign with your private key.

**Note :** Put an empty passphrase **is clearly not a good idea**. If someone get your private key, you lose the complete security of your data as your private key is not secured by a secret key. This person could decrypt all data encrypt by your public key **but also**  pretend to be you by signing with your private key. The passphrase is a **significant protection**.